# Calculating MTF: negative values in the LSF

Tags: fft

I want to implement an MTF measurement. The goal is to measure a tilted slit, like this one:

[image: Slit object]

However the first half of the LSF is positive but on the second half (white-black edge) it obviously has negative values:

[image: LSF]

Applying a FFT, I get a curve that almost always looks the same and does not really depend on sharpness alterations. In my understanding this curve is meaningless.
[image]

However, when I set all negative LSF values to zero, I get a curve that really looks like an MTF curve:

[image]

Is "*cutting off*" negative values a viable solution when measuring a slit?

I hope this is the right place to ask.

Regards

Comment: Can you please provide some more details on how you go about deriving these curves?

Comment: I generate a number of lines of the same length. These lines are shifted in the same slope as the slit. It looks like this https://imgur.com/a/2WTGmHy . Then I calculate the arithmetic mean from all lines to reduce noise. Now I have the SFR, that is a pixel array with values [0-255]. I obtain the LSF by calculating the first order derivative of the SFR. Finally, the MTF is calculated by applying a DFT algorithm to the LSF.

Comment: Or do I even have to derivate the SFR when measuring a slit? Can't I just transform the SFR to obtain the MTF curve?